# Google product API implementation

Tags: android, google-product-search

I have to implement google product list in my application.
Say, on click of a button, a list will be shown which will show the Google Products and I can acces those products.
Thanks in advace....please suggest me some code or links.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search give the answer:

http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/search/

Comment: This is deprecated now. I think this will work now https://developers.google.com/commerce-search/